# When I push from my Github actions account to pullrequest, CI stops (error?)

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

### Phenomenon

- In secrets, we have an `ACCESS_TOKEN` that contains a Personal GitHub token.
- Github Actions

```yaml
name: correction_CALLED
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  issue_comment:
    types:
      - created
      - edited

jobs:
  job_correction_CALLED:
    if: (github.event.issue.pull_request != null) && github.event.comment.body == 'correction'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      # if DIFF_CHECK=0 then **/**.tex files was not changed by textlint.
      DIFF_CHECK: 0      
    steps:
      - name: Github-Script
        uses: actions/github-script@v2
        id: set-target-branch
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          result-encoding: string
          script: |
            const pull_request = await github.pulls.get({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              pull_number: context.issue.number
            })
            return pull_request.data.head.ref
            
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ steps.set-target-branch.outputs.result }}
      - name: Clone
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: MIZOGUCHIKoki/ConfigFiles
          path: ConfigFiles
      - name: Copy files to current directory
        run: | 
          cp  ./ConfigFiles/tex_textlint/package.json ./
          cp  ./ConfigFiles/tex_textlint/.textlintrc.json ./
          cp  ./ConfigFiles/tex_textlint/package-lock.json ./
          cp  ./ConfigFiles/.gitconfig ./
            
      - name: Setup-node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 14
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install packages via packages.json
        run: |
          npm install
      - name: Correct
        run: |
          npx textlint --fix **/**.tex
      - name: Remove useless files
        if: ${{ always() }}
        run: |
          rm -rf ConfigFiles node_modules package-lock.json package.json .textlintrc.json .gitconfig
      - name: Check changed files
        run: |
          git diff >> diff.txt
          if [ -s diff.txt ];
          then
            echo "DIFF_CHECK=1" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi
      - name: Commit to current branch
        if: ${{ env.DIFF_CHECK == 1 }}
        run: | 
            git config user.name github-actions
            git config user.email 41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com
            git commit -am "Proofreading"
            git push
```

Commit & Push to a Pull Request on Github with the following trigger, and the CI that will be executed once it is posted to the Pullrequest will stop working.

- The workflow trigger you want to invoke after Push is as follows

```yaml
name: run-textlint
on: 
  push:
    paths:
      - '**/**.tex'
  pull_request_target:
    paths:
      - '**/**.tex'
  
jobs:
  run-textlint_WF:
    uses: MIZOGUCHIKoki/ConfigFiles/.github/workflows/textlint_main.yml@main
    secrets:
      gh_token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

Changed the workflow trigger you want to invoke after Push.

```yaml
- pull_request:
+ pull_request_target:
```

Comment: Please include the failure errors in your question as text, not images. The attached images are not helpful. Also, for your second workflow, is that dependent on the first job? If yes, please include that in your question along with the relevant workflow config showing that dependency. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect the `git push` from the `name: Commit to current branch` to trigger a CI, but the token used by GitHub actions has a special flag that prevents it from running another github action. This is to prevent a cascade of actions triggering more actions. You can either:

- run the steps in your CI as part of the PR, if needed use a composite action to easily reuse the code.
- Add a `on: workflow_call:` trigger to your 2nd workflow and call it explicitly from the first: `jobs: call-workflow-passing-data: uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main`
- Or, least reccomended, use a GitHub app token or Personal Access token to authenticate the push, that will trigger the subsequent action using the `on: push` trigger.

> **Warning:** [The `pull_request` and `pull_request_target` triggers have a number of security concerns](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/), since the YAML that is executed and access to the secrets are controlled by the person suggesting the changes. If your GitHub Actions permissions are set too broadly, this might grant people the ability to push arbitraty changes to your repository or approve pull requests.

> **Warning:** Instead of relying on the `$GITHUB_ENV` it's also better to use `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`, that prevents another step from setting the environment variable as you'd explicitly use the id of the previous step to reference the variable.
>
> ```
>      - name: Check changed files
>        id: diffcheck
>        run: |
>          git diff >> diff.txt
>          if [ -s diff.txt ];
>          then
>            echo "RESULT=1" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
>          fi
>      - name: Commit to current branch
>        if: ${{ steps.diffcheck.outputs.RESULT == 1 }}
>        run: | 
>            git config user.name github-actions
>            git config user.email 41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com
>            git commit -am "Proofreading"
>            git push
> ```

To pass credentials to the push you can register a credential helper to safely pass in the password:

```
    steps:
      - name: Setup git
        run: |
          git config --global credential. Helper "!f() { echo \`"username=`${GIT_USER}`npassword=`${TOKEN}\`"; }; f"
          git push
        shell: pwsh
        env:
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PUSH_TOKEN }} 
          GIT_USER: "jesse.houwing@gmail.com" # user of the PAT
```

Comment: Thank you! I choose Thant "Or, least reccomended, use a GitHub app token or Personal Access token to authenticate the push, that will trigger the subsequent action using the on: push trigger." But I can't understand how to do it. please tell me more.... And I'm a Japanese Student so sorry I'm not good at English..